# Interrupted terraform apply, now cannot destroy or apply

Tags: terraform

So I have an application that runs `terraform apply` in a directory, then can also run `terraform destroy`.  I was testing the application, and I accidentally interrupted the processes while running `apply`

Now it seems to be stuck with a partially created instance, where it recognizes the name of my instance I was creating/destroying and when I try to `apply` it says that an instance of that name already exists.  But then `destroy` says there is nothing to destroy.  So I can't do either.  Is there anyway to unsnarl this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only option is by doing:

1. execute `terraform state rm RESOURCE` example: `terraform state rm aws_ebs_volume.volume`.
2. Manually remove the resource from your cloud provider.

Answer (score 6):

you can run the below to view all current resources still live from the project directory:

```
$ terraform state list
```

to destroy each resource run the below on each individual resource:

```
$ terraform destroy --target=resource.name
```

could write a script to loop through the 'terraform state list' output if there is a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get out of this state by making sure the trailing comma was removed from the cloud provider resource definition (on AWS). Then I refreshed the state with `terraform refresh`. After that I was able to plan and apply again.